# How to format a non standard string into date format

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to select the strings '03/01/2018' and '09-NOV-17' so that the results are both in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format?

The result can also be a string.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regular expression - a plain `LIKE` is fine to do the selection of the DATE format.

Example

```
with my_data as (
select '03/01/2018' dt from dual union all
select '09-NOV-17' from dual)
select 
dt,
case when dt like '__/__/____' then to_date(dt,'dd/mm/yyyy')
when dt like '__-___-__' then  to_date(dt,'dd-mon-rr') 
end as dt_date
from my_data;
```

.

```
DT         DT_DATE            
---------- -------------------
03/01/2018 03.01.2018 00:00:00
09-NOV-17  09.11.2017 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression.  Assuming all values are in one of the two formats, you can convert to a date by doing:

```
select (case when col like '%-%-%' then to_date(col, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
             else to_date(col, 'DD-MON-YY')
        end)
```

I prefer the value in date format.  You can use `to_char()` to convert to a string format of your choosing.

Comment: I never heard a regular expression `'%-%-%'`, can you please elaborate? Perhaps you mean `LIKE '%-%-%'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit . . . Silly me.  I was going to use a regular expression to look for the right format.  Then I realized that `like` would do, because of the restriction on the value having one of the two formats.  I changed it to `like`.